# DqlBuilder don't return values but mysql do

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have method `findByTag()` which should return entites with `%#i%` but it won't. This is sql which dql builded:
`SELECT p0_.id AS id_0, p0_.content AS content_1, p0_.date AS date_2, p0_.user_id AS user_id_3 FROM post p0_ INNER JOIN user u1_ ON p0_.user_id = u1_.id LEFT JOIN points p2_ ON p0_.id = p2_.post_id LEFT JOIN comments c3_ ON p0_.id = c3_.post_id WHERE p0_.content LIKE '%#i%' ORDER BY p0_.date DESC LIMIT 20` if i enter it to mysql it return it ok.

[image: mysql]

Anybody have an idea?

```php
        $dql = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->innerJoin('p.user', 'c')
            ->leftJoin('p.points', 'pp')
            ->leftJoin('p.comments', 'cc')
            ->Where('p.content LIKE \'%#i%\'')
            ->setMaxResults($max)
            ->orderBy('p.date','DESC');
        $dql->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
        return $dql;
```

Comment: Change `$dql->getQuery()->getResult(); return $dql;` by `return $dql->getQuery()->getResult();`

Comment: @SilvioQ yes it was problem with return, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it

```
   $dql = $this->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from('YourBundleName:YourEntityName', 'p')
            ->innerJoin('YourBundleName.user', 'c')
            ->leftJoin('YourBundleName.points', 'pp')
            ->leftJoin('YourBundleName.comments', 'cc')
            ->Where('p.content LIKE \'%#i%\'')
            ->setMaxResults($max)
            ->orderBy('p.date','DESC');
        return $dql->getQuery()->getResult();
```